# Using awk to calculate 'rolling max' and print respective record from column 2

Tags: awk

Here's my file (in reality a few million rows):

```
1   75
2   188
3   279
4   267
5   100
6   28
7   479
8   325
9   225
10  181
```

I want to find the maximum of the second column for first 5 rows (rows 1-5) and print that max value but also the corresponding value from the first column. Then move to the next five rows (rows 6-10) and do the same.

The output should be:

```
3 279
7 479
```

So far I can calculate the rolling max this way:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i>maxval) maxval=$i;} NR%5==0 { print maxval; maxval= -1}' input.file
```

However, I was unable to print the respective value from the first column. I tried defining a second variable such as `want=$1` and then trying to `print maxval, want` but without success. I have a vague impression this could be done with arrays, but all my attempts were unsuccessful.

TP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that looping over *fields* is what you want here. Instead just look at the record number (or file record number to allow it to work over multiple files) modulo 5:

```
$ awk '!((FNR-1)%5) || $2 > max {x = $0; max = $2} !(FNR%5) {print x}' file
3   279
7   479
```

- if the `FNR` is 1,6,... OR `$2` is greater than the current running max, save the current row / max
- if `FNR` is 5,10,... print the current row / max

Comment: Works like a charm, very impressive; I'd have never thought of using modulo... many thanks!

Comment: @ThePresident As soon as you think "for every 5th row" you should also think "for row-number modulo 5".

Comment: @Kusalananda Very valuable advice; I'll try to remember that.

Answer (score 0):

Not an `awk` answer, but for those who like shell tools this *GNU* `split` method works:

```
split -l 5 --filter 'sort -n -k 2 | tail -1'  file
```

Comment: I get : `split: illegal option -- -
usage: split [-a sufflen] [-b byte_count] [-l line_count] [-p pattern]
             [file [prefix]]`

Comment: @ThePresident, It seems the `--filter` option might be a non-standard *GNU* `split` innovation.  There's no `--filter` listed in [*BSD* `man split`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=split&sektion=1).

Comment: That's what I came to realize as well. Thanks anyway!